# remove child from node list java

Tags: java

My xml look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<string name="string1">anything</string>
<string name="string2">anything</string>
<boolean name="bool1" value="true" />
 <boolean name="bool2" value="true" />
<long name="long1" value="1444444444" />
<long name="long2" value="1444444444" />
<long name="long3" value="1444444444" />
</config>
```

i am using nodeList

```
  try {
                    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document document = db.parse(new File("filelocation"));
                    NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("string");
                    for(int x=0,size= nodeList.getLength(); x<size; x++) {
                        String sssss = nodeList.item(x).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
                        if (sssss.equals("string2")){

                        Node node = nodeList.item(x);
                        node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);

                           // i get here i need to remove string 2 and set some value of string 1 and long1 how can i do it ?
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

so string2 should be removed and edit value of long1 and string 1
so removing string 2 is not working

Comment: And what is your question? You already figured that there are APIs to read/process XML data; are you looking for other people to tell you which methods in those APIs you might want to use to delete elements?

Comment: i need to remove the string2 but its not getting removed,its value can be anything and is unknown

Comment: Then show us the code that doesn't work. The code above only iteratores data; I dont see anything that would *remove* data.

Comment: see it again i added if string equals string2 to remove it but cant remove it

Comment: Did you try a debugger?